# D3 chart not showing up

Tags: javascript, d3.js

## Problem

Having trouble getting my chart in D3 to show up. Getting an **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input** with my `scripts.js`

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="assets/js/scripts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

## scripts.js

```
$(function() {
    var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

    var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal();

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

    var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x0)
    .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    d3.csv("assets/data/data.csv", function(error, data) {
      var ageNames = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "State"; });

      data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.ages = ageNames.map(function(name) { return {name: name, value: +d[name]}; });
    });

      x0.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.State; }));
      x1.domain(ageNames).rangeRoundBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);
      y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d3.max(d.ages, function(d) { return d.value; }); })]);

      svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

      svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Population");

      var state = svg.selectAll(".state")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "g")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.State) + ",0)"; });

      state.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) { return d.ages; })
      .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.name); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

      var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(ageNames.slice().reverse())
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

      legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 18)
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", color);

      legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 24)
      .attr("y", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d) { return d; });
});
```

### style.css

```
body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.bar {
  fill: blue;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that I got the same error when pasting your code directly into JSFiddle. It went away when I properly closed the main function. For reference, here's your code in live snippet form with the extra closing braces:

```js
var csvData = [
    {"State":0, "Age":31, "Names":["Austin"]},
    {"State":0, "Age":31, "Names":["Austin"]},
    {"State":0, "Age":31, "Names":["Austin"]},
    ];

$(function() {
    $("#placeholder").remove();
    var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

    var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal();

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

    var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x0)
    .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var data = csvData;
      var ageNames = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "State"; });

      data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.ages = ageNames.map(function(name) { return {name: name, value: +d[name]}; });
      });

      x0.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.State; }));
      x1.domain(ageNames).rangeRoundBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);
      y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d3.max(d.ages, function(d) { return d.value; }); })]);

      svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

      svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Population");

      var state = svg.selectAll(".state")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "g")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.State) + ",0)"; });

      state.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) { return d.ages; })
      .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.name); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

      var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(ageNames.slice().reverse())
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

      legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 18)
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", color);

      legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 24)
      .attr("y", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d) { return d; });
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.bar {
  fill: blue;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

On the `d3.csv("csv...")` call - try adding another `});` to the end of it.
I tried your code out on JSFiddle, and that seemed to resolve the syntax error.

**EDIT**: My bad. Left in a hurry. Here's the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/strsjpxa/

I later noticed it made more sense to close the function at the end.

Comment: Please add a link to your fiddle, or copy it here.

Comment: @rafe Can you post a link to your JSFiddle